# Make list of data frame elements conditionally

Tags: pandas

Here is what a subsection of my data frame looks like:

```
                   addresses        lats
0                     street         lat
1                316 36th St         NaN
2             1400 Broadway          NaN
3                230 5th Ave         NaN
4                630 1st Ave     40.7452
5                 18 33rd St    40.74814
6                630 1st Ave     40.7452
7              1245 Park Ave    40.78659
8                444 46th St    40.76161
9                132 36th St    40.75145
10               146 29th St    40.74728
11               255 36th St    40.75326
12  1100 Ave of the Americas  40.7550567
13       777 Westchester Ave    41.02749
14                 9 57th St    40.76386
15               880 3rd Ave      40.758
```

I would like to make a list of all of the elements in the `addresses` column that have a corresponding `nan` in the `lats` column.

The list for the given data frame would be: `['316 13th st, '1400 broadway', '230 5th ave']`.

Currently I am using the following code, but it's creating a list of ALL of the elements in `addresses`. As previously stated, I just want the elements that have `nan` in the next column. What would be an efficient way to go about doing that?

```
# creating my data frame from the columns
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None, error_bad_lines = False, usecols = [9, 28], names =
['addresses', 'lats'])
# converting the addresses column to a list
addresses = df['addresses'].tolist()
# removing any 'nan' from the addresses list (if any exist)
addresses = [x for x in addresses[1:] if str(x) != 'nan']
```

Comment: Have you tried: `addresses = df[df.lats.isnull()].addresses.tolist()` ?

Comment: @JonClements That worked, as soon as I removed `[1:]` from the line after that. I initially had that to remove `street` from the list. With your line it removes `street` because it doesn't have a null value next to it correct? So i'm safe to remove the indexing I did correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to get this list.

```
df.loc[df['lats'].isnull(), 'addresses'].tolist()

['316 36th St', '1400 Broadway', '230 5th Ave']
```

Note: As only on column is selected `addresses`, the `loc` selector returns a `Series`, this is why it is possible to use the `tolist` method.